# Captalize only month name and dayname in spanish datetime

Tags: c#

I'm converting date to Spanish using following code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
string s_date = dateValue.ToLongDateString();
```

Output is:
sábado, 04 de febrero de 2017

Now, I need to captilize DayName and MonthName. Please let me know how this can be acheived.

Expected Output:
**Sábado, 04 de Febrero de 2017**

Comment: there are only 7 days and 12 months, you can search for these 19 words, and capitalize them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("es-ES",false).TextInfo;
string s_date = textInfo.ToTitleCase( dateValue.ToLongDateString()).Replace(" De ", " de ");
```

Comment: I'm getting date in english instead of spanish. I need to captalize spanish date

Comment: Did you use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");` line?

Comment: yes now i added.. but output is: Sábado, 04 De Febrero De 2017

Comment: I dont want everyword to be captalized... only Dayname and month. It should be like: Sábado, 04 de Febrero de 2017

Comment: I edited my answer, I don't know spanish, does it solves your problem?

Comment: I will try it and let you know